# Why IIS 6 gives me error message on each asp request?

Tags: iis, asp

I have Windows Server 2003 with IIS6. Every time I request something that ends with .asp server returns a 404 error, but not a usual one, the error response is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 93
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2011 07:14:27 GMT
Connection: close

<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>�� ������� ����� ��������� ����.
</body></html>
```

What's the origin of this error and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your ISAPI mapping for the .asp extension is broken.  I see the same thing when I'm debugging ISAPI served PHP on IIS6.

Your error code looks like a 'friendly' error.  That's set in IIS6 as well.  Try to get proper error messages.  Also, check the IIS logs and Windows logs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using a basic .HTML file to see if the same issue happens?

Also have you added in *page*.asp into IIS as an allowed document type?

Al

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Dan: also, 404 is a response the Web Service Extensions list will send to a client if the .ASP extension isn't explictly allowed from that interface.

There'll be a substatus code logged in the web logs that you can search on to more closely identify that item.

Check that:

- ASP is enabled in SYSOCMGR (Add/Remove->Windows Features)
- Active Server Pages is allowed in Web Service Extensions in the IIS MMC
- Script permission is granted on the folder you're interested in
- There's a script mapping for .ASP at that folder (or any parent folders)